# Find all relations starting with a given node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In a graph where the following nodes

> A,B,C,D

have a relationship with each nodes successor

> (A->B)

and

> (B->C)

etc.

How do i make a query that starts with A and gives me all nodes (and relationships) from that and outwards.
I do **not** know the end node (C).

All i know is to start from A, and traverse the whole connected graph (with conditions on relationship and node type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the nodes / relationships starting at a node:

```
MATCH (a:A {id: "id"})-[r*]-(b)
RETURN a, r, b
```

This will return all the graphs originating with node A / Label A where id = "id".

One caveat - if this graph is large the query will take a long time to run.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need to use this pattern:
`(n)-[*]->(m)` - variable length path of any number of relationships from n to m. (see [Refcard](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-refcard/))

A sample query would be:

```
MATCH path = (a:A)-[*]->()
RETURN path
```

Have also a look at the path functions in the refcard to expand your cypher query (I don't know what exact conditions you'll need to apply).